When does tidyverts recognize forecast variable transformations?
I'm trying to complete a forecasting project in the tidyverts framework. That includes R packages tsibble, fable, fabletools, feasts, etc. It's described in the online book Forecasting Principles and Practice.
Q: How can I know when a tidyverts model (e.g., ARIMA(), used like dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y)) %>% forecast(h=12)) will acknowledge and back-transform a transformed target variable y?
The post Non-Gaussian forecasting using fable demonstrates that a Box-Cox transformation fabletools::box_cox(y, lambda) is acknowledged and back-transformed, at least when used within fable::ETS() as dat %>% model(ets=ETS(box_cox(y,lamda))). The section Complex Seasonality demonstrates that sqrt(y) is acknowledged and back-transformed, at least when used within fable::STL().
Q: More generally, how can I simply see which models recognize which transformations and their back-transformations? Is it simply documented somewhere? Is there a simple function I use on an ARIMA object to tell me what transforms are available? Maybe this is a simple S3 or R6 thing? If so, still, let me know, not leaving out details, as I don't know my way around S3 or R6 objects yet.
I wrote some code below to demonstrate how I've been getting surprised. The forecasts for my garima model turned out to be negative. Since my garima model used ARIMA(box_cox(y,0.5)), the back-transform should basically be the squared function, which can't be negative. So, something is off here. Maybe ARIMA() does not recognize box_cox()? Or maybe this is just because inv_box_cox(z,0.5)!=z^2. Regardless, it would just be nice to quickly check whether ARIMA() recognizes box_cox(), or any other transformations.
# simulate
set.seed(10)
len=36
aa <- exp(-0.1*(1:len) + rnorm(len,sd=0.1))
ab <- exp(-0.2*(1:len) + rnorm(len,sd=0.1))
tibble(aa=aa,ab=ab) %>%
  mutate(ym=make_yearmonth(year=2021,month=1)+0:(len-1)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c('aa','ab'),names_to='key', values_to='val') %>%
  as_tsibble(index=ym, key=key) ->
  dat

# fit and forecast
dat %>% 
  model(
    garima=ARIMA(box_cox(val,0.5)),
    gets=ETS(box_cox(val,0.5)),
  ) ->
  fit
fit %>% forecast(h=36) -> fcs
fcs %>% autoplot(level=NULL)
fcs %>% filter(.mean<0) %>% distinct(key, .model)
# So, ARIMA doesn't back-transform?
# A tibble: 1 × 2
# key   .model
# <chr> <chr> 
# 1 aa    garima

fit %>% pluck('garima', 1, 'transformation') 
#[[1]]
#Transformation: box_cox(val, 0.5)
#Backtransformation: inv_box_cox(val, 0.5)
## This is nice, it seems ARIMA is recognizing the box_cox transform? 
## But still, what other transforms does it recognize?
## What are my options?

fit %>% pluck('garima', 1, 'model', 'specials') 
#<environment: 0x00000203ba8c0058>
#attr(,"required_specials")
#[1] "pdq" "PDQ"
#attr(,"xreg_specials")
#[1] "trend"   "season"  "fourier"
## This is nice too. It shows me all the available specials, even though I didn't use any.
## Does something like this exist for all the available transformations for use, but may not have been used?


All transformations should be handled, even user-defined transformations. See the package vignette for a full explanation. https://fable.tidyverts.org/articles/transformations.html
A Box-Cox transformation with lambda = 0.5 is given by z = 2(y^(0.5) - 1). So the inverse is (0.5 z + 1)^2. However, fable doesn't actually use a Box-Cox transformation (despite the name of the function). It is using a modified Box-Cox due to Bickel and Doksum (see https://otexts.com/fpp3/transformations.html#mathematical-transformations). The modified version has inverse transformation sign(0.5z+1) * (0.5z+1)^2. So it is possible to get negative values.
If you want to use a square root, just use a square root. e.g., ARIMA(sqrt(val)).
If you want to use a genuine Box-Cox transformation (not the modified Bickel-Doksum version), you can write your own transformation function as explained in the package vignette.
You can always see that the transformation has been reversed in the forecasts by looking at the forecast object. In this case, you get

# A fable: 144 x 5 [1M]
# Key:     key, .model [4]
   key   .model       ym                val  .mean
   <chr> <chr>     <mth>             <dist>  <dbl>
 1 aa    garima 2024 Jan  t(N(-1.7, 0.003)) 0.0204
 2 aa    garima 2024 Feb t(N(-1.7, 0.0069)) 0.0178
 3 aa    garima 2024 Mar  t(N(-1.8, 0.012)) 0.0157

The column val shows that you have transformed Normal distributions. The t() means a transformation has been applied.

Clarification: how can I know which transform/back-transform pairs are handled automatically for a model? E.g., your linked writings demonstrate that x+1, log(x), sqrt(x), and combos of these are all handled automatically. I.e., there's no need for a user to define them and their inv and transforms. But that's not so for the scaled logit. Also, e.g., what about x^2, which doesn't have a unique inv? I looked through fable code on GitHub and did see any sqrt, with its inv, hard-wired in there. So, does that mean fable tries a numerical inv of any transform you attempt? Thanks Rob!

Transformations are currently assumed (and not tested) to be monotonically increasing on the domain of the data, and so the current implementation will invert sqrt(x) <-> x^2.
